# Combining steps in git workflow

Tags: git, pycharm

In my project setup I have three main branches: development, staging and master (i.e. production). I develop on development or a feature branch off that. When it comes to moving something to production, I'll commit and push my development branch, then checkout staging, merge development, then push that. Same process applies for staging -> master. That's a lot of steps (commit, push, checkout, merge, push). Is there a faster way to roll these into one?

I'm using PyCharm as my IDE (though this should be the same for any of the JetBrains IDEs such as IntelliJ-IDEA), so something which fits into that would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: you can simply live with two branches: `feature` and `master`, [GitHub-flow style](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html).

[image: github flow]

Less branches, less merges.

But you could setup several repos:

- one for development (where you have one or multiple feature branches)
- one for staging (where you merge into master the branch that you want to test in staging)
- one for prod (with just the master branch, updated from pushes from staging)

In other word, don't mix-up:

- development lifecycle steps (dev, staging, prod)
- with merge workflow (`feature` vs. `master`)